# Password update Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, passwords, cpanel

We got a guy in India to help us do some SEO work on our Wordpress website. In fact he's done very little and is now asking for more money so we need to lock him out. I've changed the password in cPanel and I've changed the password for the only user (Admin) in Wordpress itself. I'm concerned that he may be able to get in by some other means such as phpMyAdmin. Can anyone advise on this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he can get in by phpMyAdmin. Maybe you should try changing the cpanel password, or you can keep the 2 way authentication while logging in the wp-admin.

Comment: Yes, I've changed the password for cPanel. Or do you mean the phpMyAdmin password under Databases in cPanel? And if so, would this mean changing something in Wordpress so it knows the new password?

Comment: yes, you can also change the password for the phpMyAdmin, but be sure you change it in the wp-config file too.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply change your hosting login details and also delete FTP details from your host

Answer (score 0):

You can check following parameters to secure your wp-admin password and wp-admin access as well

1. Update the cpanel password
2. Change the username and pw of database(if you have create for database).
3. Change the FTP access or delete

And my recommended secure the wp-admin by IP just add the code in ht-access and you can open the wp-admin by particular IP address (**If you have static IP than once you added IP in htaccess you do not need to add again but if do not have you have to change once per session**) yes it is hatching but security never comes less

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.10$ (Here is your IP address $ sign need at end)  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```